# Mysqli can't execute 2 query on the same connection

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to execute 2 different query with the same mysqli connection.
I tried to use multi_query($query) as in the following code:

```
<?php 
$re = $mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
$query = "CALL LDmodel_tree();CALL LDmodel_file()";
$mysqli->multi_query($query);

echo 'var fold = [];'."\n";
echo 'var file = [];'."\n";


$result = $mysqli->store_result();
while ($rsto = $result->fetch_row()) 
        {
        $y=0;$cart = array ();
        do {$cart[$x][$y] = $rsto[$y]; $y++; } while ($y<4);
        echo 'fold['.$x.'] = ['.$cart[$x][3].',"'.$cart[$x][1].'",'.$cart[$x][0].','.$cart[$x][2].'];'."\n";        /* ID, nome, livello, madre */
        $x++;
        }          

$result->free();
echo 'var n_cart='.$x.';'."\n";


$result = $mysqli->next_result();
while ($rsto = $result->fetch_row())
        {
        $y=0;$cart = array ();
        do {$cart[$x][$y] = $rsto[$y]; $y++; } while ($y<6);
        echo 'file['.$x.'] = ['.$cart[$x][0].',"'.$cart[$x][1].'","'.$cart[$x][2].'",'.$cart[$x][3].','.$cart[$x][4].','.$cart[$x][5].'];'."\n";
        $x++;
        }          
$result->free();
echo 'var n_file='.$nx.';'."\n";
?>
```

After the first query, it fires this error :

Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in **E:\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\MOD_tree.php** on line25

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli::next_result()` returns a boolean. Use `mysqli::store_result()` to retrieve the next result.

https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php

Comment: Code changed in :

$result = $mysqli->store_result();
while ($rsto = $result->fetch_row())
  {
              ......
  }      
$result->free();

but with no improvments. 

Do I need to add the 'more_result' statement ?

Comment: Did that answer your question? If so, you can accept this answer by clicking the link on the left.